# Complete checkout in multiple currencies

Tags: price, payment, multicurrency, currency-rates

I am trying to set up a multiple currency store, we are selling to the UK and Ireland and want to settle payments and taxes in both countries. We cannot have a straight up currency conversion because we need to charge differently depending on country as costs vary.

My ideal situation is that someone from Ireland will see the the Euro website, complete checkout and get charged in Euro and this will get settled in an Irish bank account, someone from the UK will see the GBP website, complete checkout and get charged in GBP and this will go into a UK bank account. We want to be able to input different values in Euro and GBP on the backend as well.

My base currency is GBP and at the moment I have just a 1:1 currency conversion so that when I go to the Euro section I can just enter the Euro price, if I change the conversion rate we will need to do calculations from euro to GBP just so we can enter it and have it display back as euro on the front end which makes no sense.
[image]

Then when users are in the Euro site and go to checkout I want them to be able to check out in that currency. Not having a euro price but getting charged in GBP.

[image]

Braintree payment gateway can take and settle multiple currencies in different countries but is this possible with Magento?

Comment: Using Magento 2.1.11

Comment: Ok figured out what I was doing wrong and fixed the base currency at the website level but still when the payment is being processed its still going through as GBP